# Perl -- commit-msg hook doesn't stop the commit when exiting 1

Tags: git, perl, githooks, git-commit

**Context :**

I am using some git-hooks to apply automatically some formatting options on Perl scripts. On a pre-commit hook I clean and reformat my scripts using perltidy. I want to check what the user put on the commit message and if it's empty or it's equivalent to "abort", we want to prevent the commit and undo the formatting modifications.

**Problem :**

I removed the .sample extension of the git hook and made it executable using `chmod u+x .git/hooks/commit-msg` but when my script `exit 1` the commit isn't stop like it should.

> **commit-msg**
>
> This hook is invoked by git-commit[1] and git-merge[1], and can be bypassed with the --no-verify option. It takes a single parameter, the name of the file that holds the proposed commit log message. Exiting with a non-zero status causes the command to abort.

source : https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_commit_msg

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

# Get the path to the files in which we have the commit message
my $commit_file = $ARGV[0];

# Read the file and extract the commit message (lines which don't start with #) 
my @commit_msg;
open(my $fh, "<", "$commit_file");
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    if (substr($line, 0, 1) ne "#") {
        push(@commit_msg, $line);
    }
}

# Check the message isn't empty or we don't have a "abort" line
my $boolean = 0;
foreach my $line (@commit_msg) {
    if ($line ne "abort" && $line ne "") {
        $boolean = 1;
    }
}

if ($boolean == 0) {
    print "We should commit the modifications\n";
    exit 0; # Don't prevent commit
}
else {
    print "We shouldn't commit the modifications\n";
    exit 1; # Prevent commit
}
```

The script is executable and works ! If I enter "abort" when I commit some stuff, it prints "We shouldn't commit the modifications" but commit them discarding the exit 1...

I hope someone will be able to help ! I am new with git-hook and can't find a solution. Perhaps I miss something on Stackoverflow but I didn't find a post answering this issue.

Best,

Antoine

**Edit :**
 I don't commit using : `--no-verify`

Comment: Are you sure the option `--no-verify` isn't enabled?

Comment: 100 % sure.
I just call : `git commit` and then I enter my commit message.

Comment: Are you sure it commits anything? For me, it aborts the commit always, as each line contains at least the final newline, so it's never "abort" or "".

Comment: Well yes... If I do `git status` after that, it tells me that I have nothing to commit right know. And it catchs "abort" or "" because if I commit with ""/"abort" message, I print "We shouldn't commit the modifications" !

Comment: At that point I'd get out the big guns and run `strace -f -o wtf.log git commit` to see what the heck is going on.

Comment: @AntoineMaugein `$line` can never be `""`.

Comment: That doesn't follow.

Comment: Using : `strace -f -o wtf.log git commit`, I see that the last log line tells me : "+++ exited with 1 +++" so it should not be committed. But if I do `git status`, my file isn't present, I can't add it and I don't see a modified file.

Comment: Why `git status`? What does `git log -p` say?

Comment: Git status gives me the changes to be committed no ? I should still see my file when I do git status if I prevent the last commit no ?

Comment: Well.... `git log -p` tells me that the last commit is a few days ago... That's mean that I haven't committed any new changes and that the pre commit work...  I don't get it

Comment: Why if the commit have been aborted, I don't see that I have changes to commit when I do git status... ?
Anyway thanks for the help :)

Comment: Isn't the logic reversed? "abort" doesn't lead to preventing of the commit...

Comment: Does `git diff --cached` show anything?

Comment: It doesn't show any diff even using --cached

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I first installed your hook, I wasn’t able to get it to commit *anything*, but that’s because the hook has too many negatives. Your language teacher’s admonitions to avoid double negatives will help you out when writing software too. The hook attempts to look for a valid condition by testing in the negative sense if a line looks good, set `$boolean` to 1 if so, but then `exit 0` (indicating success) only if `$boolean` was 0.

The non-descript name `$boolean` is likely responsible in part. You may have lost track of your intended meaning between setting it and which exit status you wanted to produce. Further, your intent behind the logic will fail as long as the last line of the commit message is valid.

The code below functions in the way you want with git 2.17.1.

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

die "Usage: $0 commit-log-message\n" unless @ARGV == 1; # (1)

# Get the path to the files in which we have the commit message
my $commit_file = shift; # (2)

# Read the file and extract the commit message (lines which don't start with #) 
my $commit_msg = "";
open my $fh, "<", $commit_file or die "$0: open $commit_file: $!"; # (3)
while (<$fh>) {        # (4)
    next if /^#/;      # (5)
    $commit_msg .= $_;
}

# Check the message isn't empty or we don't have an "abort" line
my $valid_commit_msg = $commit_msg ne "" && $commit_msg !~ /^abort$/m; # (6)

if ($valid_commit_msg) { # (7)
    print "We should commit the modifications\n";
    exit 0; # Don't prevent commit
}
else {
    print "We shouldn't commit the modifications\n";
    exit 1; # Prevent commit
}
```

**(1)** Yes, git is supposed to provide the name of the file with the log message, but sanity check for it in case the code gets copied or otherwise installed in the wrong hook.

**(2)** Pluck the argument from `@ARGV` with `shift`.

**(3)** Always, *always*, **always** check the return value from `open`. Note that the error message if it does fail contains the name of the program that had the error (`$0`), what it was trying to do (`"open $commit_file"`), and the error (`$!`). Develop this habit. It will save you a lot of frustration one day.

**(4)** Rather than copying lines into an array, concatenate them all into a single scalar. Use `while (<$fh>) { ... }` to see each line in `$_`, which is more idiomatic Perl and declutters your code.

**(5)** Skipping comment lines then becomes a simple `next if /^#/;`.

**(6)** Say what you mean. Rather than the mechanism (`$boolean`) name your intention. You want to know that a commit message is valid before letting it pass. A valid commit message must meet two conditions:

- The commit message is non-empty.
- The commit message does not have any line whose sole contents are `abort`.

Rendered in Perl, this is

```
my $valid_commit_msg = $commit_msg ne "" && $commit_msg !~ /^abort$/m;
```

A couple of notes:

- The `!~` operator inverts the sense of the regex match, *i.e.*, `$commit_msg` must *not* contain `abort`.
- The `/m` switch at the end of the pattern is for multi-line mode. It makes the `^` and `$` anchors match at the beginning and end of lines within the target rather than the leftmost and rightmost characters only.

**(7)** Use `$valid_commit_msg` as a boolean in a way that reads naturally.

```
if ($valid_commit_msg) { ... }
```

is preferable to `if ($valid_commit_msg == 0) { ... }` because the 0 value was the wrong one, repeating the good value is redundant, and a value hanging out at the end is easy to overlook.

Comment: Hello ! Thank you for the answer ! I'd like more informations : 1. why is it preferable to use shift than ARGV here ? (2)

Comment: @Antoine It is arguably more idiomatic or elegant Perl where we tend to have a slight bias against indexing by individual array indices with `$array[$i]` or string indices with `substr`. Another way to write it is `my($commit_file) = @ARGV;`. Note that the parentheses around the `my` list are important because they impart list context, and that way `$commit_file` takes the value of the first element in `@ARGV`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic in your script is reversed, i.e. the word `abort` doesn't lead to exit code 1.

I think the following should work:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my($commit_msg_file) = @ARGV
    or die "usage: $0 <commit message file>\n";

open(my $fh, '<', $commit_msg_file);
my $do_commit;
while (<$fh>) {
    # skip comment or empty lines
    next if /^#/ || /^\s*$/;

    # check for the word "abort" on its own line
    last if (/^abort$/);

    # at least one non-empty non-comment line detected
    $do_commit++;
    last;
}
close($fh);

if ($do_commit) {
    print "We should commit the modifications\n";
    exit 0; # Don't prevent commit
}

print "We shouldn't commit the modifications\n";
exit 1; # Prevent commit
```